# Custom event does not reach caller

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, flash-cs5

I made a custom event that's supposed to be fired when a specific function within a class is executed. I listen for this event from within my main script, frame one of my timeline. See the code to understand my question a bit better.

My CustomEvents.as

```
package  {
    import flash.events.Event;  
        public class CustomEvents extends Event {

            public static const PAGE_EMPTY:String = "Page Empty";

            public function CustomEvents(type:String) {
                super(type);
                trace("hello from within the event class!");
            }
        }   
}
```

The function within FRONT_PAGE.as that dispatches the event

```
public function exitPage(){

        dispatchEvent(new CustomEvents(CustomEvents.PAGE_EMPTY));

        var mainLinkExitMove:Tween = new Tween(mainLink, "y", Strong.easeOut, mainLink.y , -150, 3, true);          
        var gridExitMove:Tween = new Tween(grid, "y", Strong.easeOut, grid.y , -150, 3, true);

}
```

And finally the code that calls the above function, and listens for the returned event.
frontPage is an object of the FRONT_PAGE.as class, declared earlier in the code.

```
function gotoSubPage(){
    frontPage.exitPage();

    frontPage.addEventListener(CustomEvents.PAGE_EMPTY, ef_FrontPageFinishedExiting);
    function ef_FrontPageFinishedExiting(event:CustomEvents){
        trace("Event has been caught");
    }
}
```

I know I am reaching the CustomEvents constructor, as the trace within it gets printed.
The problem is it seems like the event does not reach the function caller?

I was unable to find good examples of how to use simple custom events, so this is how I think it's supposed to be. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's not working because you're listening for the event after calling the method that dispatches the event, cart before horse :)

Your're also declaring `ef_FrontPageFinishedExiting` within `gotoSubPage`, it should be outside of that method within the class.

Try this instead:

```
function gotoSubPage() {
    frontPage.addEventListener(CustomEvents.PAGE_EMPTY, ef_FrontPageFinishedExiting);
    frontPage.exitPage();   
}

function ef_FrontPageFinishedExiting(event:CustomEvents) {
    trace("Event has been caught");
}
```

Also when you have a custom event it's a good idea to override the clone method as well:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MyEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const SOMETHING_HAPPENED:String = "somethingHappened";

        public function MyEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }

        override public function clone():Event
        {
            return new MyEvent( type, bubbles, cancelable );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked!

I have no idea how the Event class work, I just use it :/

Do you mind explaining what the clone() method is for please?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to define a new Event Class just to create a new type.  If you want that type to be a constant, fine, but your constants can be stored in a file that just stores constant values. http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2007/08/dispatching-events.html

Comment: @AmyBlankenship that's true, what I left out (and your post describes) was if you want some data passed along with the event you need a custom event.